# How can I merge multiple data frames with the same columns in R?

Tags: r

I want to join multiple data frames(5), they are exactly equal to this sample:
Place1

```
   Date        Sales Price SKU
    2007/01/02   1     1.29 52648
    2007/01/02   2     1.99 48721
    2007/01/02   5     0.55 65897
    2007/01/02   2     5.00 56482
    2007/01/02   10    2.50 46521
```

different data frames have the same columns but different rows and I want to join them.
I tried with the function merge but only let me do with 2.
How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your data have exactly the same columns and you are just looking to join them, you are generally not looking for `merge` but for `rbind`.

Since the number of `data.frame`s is small, you should be able to just do:

```
rbind(Place1, Place2, Place3, Place4, Place5)
```

Alternatively, if you can get these all in a `list`, you can use:

```
do.call(rbind, your-list-of-dataframes)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want!

Comment: What is this is not what I want, and I want to merge four tables from the census, one for each year? Same fields each time.

Answer (score 2):

Try rbind function:

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

or, if all df are in a list called dflist:

```
do.call(rbind, dflist)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want!